# Javascript Not Running in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
 <tr class='foo'><td>one</td></tr>
 <tr class='foo'><td>two</td></tr>
 <tr class='foo'><td>three</td></tr>
</table>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javscript"  src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d25940992da18e05f3f2d50889f6a4c2/raw/f013565c33d17abb33a4f5ad7717aae090873516/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### JS

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var hasChildren, rowsWithChildren;

  $(function() {
    return console.log('starting');
  });

  $(function() {
    var filtered, rows;
    console.log('here');
    rows = $('tr');
    filtered = rowsWithChildren(rows);
    return console.log(filtered);
  });

  rowsWithChildren = function(rows) {
    return _.filter(rows, function(r) {
      return hasChildren(r);
    });
  };

  hasChildren = function(row) {
    return row.children().length === 1;
  };

}).call(this);
```

When I open that HTML page in my Chrome Browser, I see the table on the screen. But, I don't see any `console.log ...` statements in the output of the Developer Tools `Console`.

Also, when I look at Dev Tool's `Sources`, I don't see the JS from `gist.github.com...`.

What's wrong with this HTML?

Comment: which version, as i am getting printed (starting, here), please try with preserve log checkbox

Comment: I'd expect to see a mixed content error somewhere since you are mixing HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: `text/javscript`: check your spelling!

Comment: console displays TypeError: row.children is not a function

Comment: What trincot said. And after that you will get the error: "Refused to execute script from '`https://gist....test.js`' because its MIME type ('`text/plain`') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third `script` element has a wrong `type` value. With a wrong value, the loaded file will not be interpreted as JavaScript.

So change:

```
<script type="text/javscript"  ...
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There's two problems with what you're attempting to do:

1. There's a typo on the line where you link to the Gist - should be `text/javascript` not `text/javscript`.
2. Github doesn't allow you to hotlink to code/assets hosted on their website - essentially you can't use them as a CDN. [Here's a blog post from them explaining this in more detail.](https://github.com/blog/1482-)

Answer (score -1):

As I remember there is "onready" problem in this version of jQuery (I may be mistaken).

As for "text/javascript" it's unnecessary nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

Try to merge your two $(function(){}) into one, and remove these "returns" inside them. Like this:

```
    (function() {
      var hasChildren, rowsWithChildren;

      $(function() {
        console.log('starting');

        var filtered, rows;
        console.log('here');
        rows = $('tr');
        filtered = rowsWithChildren(rows);
        console.log(filtered);
      });

      rowsWithChildren = function(rows) {
        return _.filter(rows, function(r) {
          return hasChildren(r);
        });
      };

      hasChildren = function(row) {
        return row.children().length === 1;
      };

    }).call(this);
```

Hope it helps.